# Prevent LED Recessed Lighting Trim from getting stuck - Springs vs. Friction

Tags: led, recessed-lighting, retrofit

This is a more specific & up-to-date version of this question:

[LED Recessed lighting trim stuck](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139565/led-recessed-lighting-trim-stuck)

The goal is prevention, so this is not a duplicate.

Some new-construction cans (especially it seems 6" cans) typically have "V" shaped springs that hold the light fixture in place. These springs engage with slots in the housing.

For example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Feit-Electric-5-6-in-75W-Equivalent-Soft-White-2700K-Dimmable-CEC-Integrated-LED-Retrofit-White-Recessed-Light-Trim-Downlight-6-Pack-LEDR56B927CAMP6/304142655

However, many 4" cans (e.g. HALO) don't have the internal bracket for such a scheme and expect the trim to be held in place by 3 spring tabs spaced equally around the perimeter of the trim.  These 3 tabs are frequently seen on LED retrofit trims at retailers like Home Depot.

For example: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-Contractor-Select-E-Series-4-in-3000K-Soft-White-Integrated-LED-720-Lumens-Recessed-Retrofit-Baffle-Trim-4BEMW-LED-30K-90CRI-M6/313471813

I have noticed that these tabs/legs are sharp and tend to cut grooves into the metal of the can and can become very difficult to remove.  This is a significant problem because it becomes very difficult to replace the retrofit module if desired or necessary.

This might (or might not) be the root problem of the original poster linked above (there isn't enough information to tell).

However, my question is this:

Before installing 40 retrofits like this, I need to make sure I can remove them in the future if desired.
Does anyone have experience with these kinds of mounting springs and have any suggestions on how to make them easier to remove?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've always used a scrap piece of solid copper wire with a hook bent on one end. Move the retrofit to one side of the can, insert the wire and hook on to the spring, pull the wire hook and lower the retrofit. Then do the same thing on the other springs. You will have to do this a few times and "walk" the retrofit out. Once you get your retrofits, practice a few times just to get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually have a retrofit to experiment, but haven't been having good luck with that. I have managed to get it out on a table where i can get at any angle, but can't imagine doing it while the thing is mounted to the ceiling.

Comment: Was hoping there might be a trick like "wrap duct tape around the springs to make them easier to slide out" or something.

Comment: @Brad  That could work but you don't want them sliding out too easily. I never tried it because I didn't want a bunch of "call backs" because lights were hanging by the wires.:-)